# How and why do the [[prototype]] slots of instances contain the Constructor.prototype at the point in time they were made (and don't get 'updated')?

Tags: javascript

If you change `Constructor.prototype`, instances of `Constructor` you made before the change will 'store' the old `Constructor.prototype` in their `[[prototype]]` slot.

```js
function F() {
}

o1 = new F();

F.prototype = {color: "red"};

o2 = new F();

console.log(o1) //it's [[proto]] contains old Object.prototype.
console.log(o2) //it's [[proto]] contains {color: "red"}.
```

I was under the impression the `[[prototype]]` slot references `Object.prototype`. How does it capture the old `Object.prototype`?

Comment: It's not possible to reference a slot in JavaScript, only values. So the `[[prototype]]` slot references the original prototype object. Reassigning `F.prototype` has no effect on the original object.

Comment: @Barmar So how does filling in the `[[prototype]]` of an object work? Make a copy of `Constructor.prototype` at that point in time? Is it something we don't need to concern ourselves with so long as we remember the rule my question describes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing magic about the `[[proto]]` slot, it's just like any other object property in that it can contain a reference to an object. It's not linked directly to the `F.prototype` slot, it just gets a reference to the value of that slot when the object is created.

So reassigning the `F.prototype` slot has no effect on the other references to the prototype object, just like any other object property:

```
o1 = { prop1: {a: 1}}
o2 = { prop1: o1.prop1 }
console.log(o2.prop1.a) // prints 1
o1.prop1 = {a: 2}
console.log(o2.prop1.a) // still prints 1
```

This is why we don't usually reasign `F.prototype` after we've created instances of the class. Instead, we assign to properties of `F.prototype`; since all the instances reference this object, modifying it in place affects all of them.

So in your example you would do:

```
F.prototype.color = "red";
```

Comment: It references the object, but not the slot in `o1`. Do you know how pointers work in C? If so, I can explain it by analogy.